# cannot find the library `/usr/lib64/libexpat.la' when building httpd-2.4.7 RPM for CentOS 6.5

Tags: apache2, centos6, rpmbuild

I am following up the instruction from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/rpm.html
to build httpd-2.4.7 RPM for CentOS6.5. But I got the following errors - cannot find the library `/usr/lib64/libexpat.la'.

**rpmbuild -tb httpd-2.4.7.tar.bz2**

.....
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -pthread  -O2 -g -pie      -o htpasswd  htpasswd.lo passwd_common.lo      /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.la -ldb-4.3 -lexpat -ldb-4.3 /usr/lib64/libapr-1.la -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
libtool: link: **cannot find the library `/usr/lib64/libexpat.la' or unhandled argument`/usr/lib64/libexpat.la'**
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/httpd-2.4.7/support'<br>
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1<br>
make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/httpd-2.4.7/support'

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iSxbcs (%build)
RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iSxbcs (%build)

I ran **yum search libexpat**, the package has been installed.

[root@localhost Downloads]# yum search libexpat
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.les.net
 * extras: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * updates: mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca
======= Matched: libexpat ==========================
compat-expat1.i686 : A library for parsing XML documents
compat-expat1.x86_64 : A library for parsing XML documents
expat.i686 : An XML parser library
**expat.x86_64 : An XML parser library**
expat-devel.i686 : Libraries and header files to develop applications using expat
expat-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files to develop applications using expat
mingw32-expat.noarch : MinGW Windows port of expat XML parser library

Anyone knows how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 2):

The INSTALL doc states that you can:

```
./configure --with-included-apr
```

to use APR and APR-util libraries which include `libexpat.la` and come with httpd.

Answer (score 0):

A `.la` file is for `libtool` to know how to link a library. It's probably in `expat-devel`, and should be added to the `.spec` file as a `BuildRequires`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how to verify .spec file and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install apr and apr-util before installing apache.

libexpat.la comes along with the source code of apr-util.

Try copying source code directory of apr and apr-util into srclib directory of apache and use `./configure --with-included-apr`. This solved my issue.

```
cp -r /path/of/apr /path/of/apache/srclib/

cp -r /path/of/apr-util /path/of/apache/srclib/

./configure --with-included-apr
```